# Allow Deny rules in htaccess php, apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is there any difference between these 2:

order deny,allow
deny from 111.111.111.111
allow from all

order allow,deny
deny from 111.111.111.111
allow from all

Comment: Yes, it is described in docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in a `deny,allow` situation, if a match is made in both deny and allow chain, it will default to the second chain. The same goes the other way around, in a `allow,deny` situation, if a match is made in both chains, the second chain takes precedence.

There is a good table in the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order)

Comment: So if it is order deny,allow; then if I connect from 111.111.111.111, I will be allowed? But if it is allow,deny, I will be not?